# Make div's height expand as per content height and width

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is my html structure

```js
$('.product').click(function(){   
  var $this = $(this).find('.product-desc');
  $(".product-desc").not($this).hide('slow');   
  $this.toggle('slow');  
})
```

```css
.prod-container>.col-md-3 {
  padding: 0 6px;
}

.prooduct-title img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/*.prooduct-title img {
    min-width: 70%;
    max-height: 105px;
    margin: 5px 20px;
}*/

.product {
  background: linear-gradient(-58deg, #0057a0, #00b8e1);
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 12px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
      display: inline-block;
}

.prooduct-title {
  min-height: 105px;
  display: flex;
  height: 121px;
}

.prooduct-title>div {
  padding: 0;
}

.products-section .col-md-10 .col-md-3 {
  padding: 0 6px;
}

.products-section {
  margin: 7px 0;
}

.prod-title {
  /*padding: 10px!important;*/
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.prod-title p {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 18px;
}

.product-desc ul {
  padding: 0px 0px 0 0px;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: none;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}

.product-desc ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px 18px 5px 28px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.product-desc ul li:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.product-desc ul li a,
.product-desc ul li a:active,
.product-desc ul li a:focus,
.product-desc ul li a:hover {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.product-desc ul li>p:first-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
}

.product-desc ul li>p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.product-desc ul li a>p:last-child {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.vertical-track {
  width: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.vertical-handle {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.product-desc ul+div {
  right: 10px!important;
  left: auto!important;
}

.search-results {
  background: rgba(233, 233, 233, 0.9);
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -10px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -10px #000000;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -10px #000000;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 100%;
}

.results.default-skin.scrollable {
  border-radius: 0;
}

.results.default-skin.scrollable a {
  padding: 10px;
}

.results.default-skin.scrollable a:hover {
  background-color: #1a3a5f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prod-container clearfix">
          

  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
     <div class="product clearfix" style="background: linear-gradient(-58deg, #0057a0, #00b8e1);">
       <div class="prooduct-title clearfix">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
         <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 prod-title">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-desc" style="display:none;">
     <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     </ul>
        <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
     </div>
     
     
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="product clearfix" style="background: linear-gradient(-58deg, #d23a36, #ed6e26);">
       <div class="prooduct-title clearfix">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
         <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 prod-title">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-desc" style="display:none;">
     <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="product clearfix" style="background: linear-gradient(-58deg, #3dbb9b, #69c074);">
       <div class="prooduct-title clearfix">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
         <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 prod-title">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-desc" style="display:none;">
    <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="product clearfix" style="background: linear-gradient(-58deg, #008fad, #00b4db);">
       <div class="prooduct-title clearfix">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
         <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 prod-title">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-desc" style="display:none;">
    <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
     </div>
     
     
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="product clearfix" style="background: linear-gradient(-58deg, #464a52, #5a5e65);">
       <div class="prooduct-title">      
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
         <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 prod-title">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-desc" style="display:none;">
    <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Screw</p>
       <p>0 Battle Card</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="product clearfix" style="background: linear-gradient(-58deg, #b6b820, #d5d425 );">
       <div class="prooduct-title"> 
         <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
         <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 prod-title">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
       
    </div>
    <div class="product-desc" style="display:none;">
     <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="product clearfix" style="background: linear-gradient(-58deg, #6fa031, #82b83a);">
       <div class="prooduct-title clearfix">
     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
         <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 prod-title">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="product-desc" style="display:none;">
    <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
     </div>
     
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="product clearfix" style="background: linear-gradient(-58deg, #00b7a8, #00b7a8);">
       <div class="prooduct-title clearfix">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
         <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 prod-title">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-desc" style="display:none;">
    <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="product clearfix" style="background: linear-gradient(-58deg, #f79227, #fcb335);">
       <div class="prooduct-title">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
         <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 prod-title">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-desc" style="display:none;">
    <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
     </div>
     
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="product clearfix" style="background: linear-gradient(-58deg, #838383, #9b9b9b);">
       <div class="prooduct-title clearfix">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
         <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 prod-title">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="product-desc" style="display:none;">
    <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </a>
     </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
     </div>
  </div>
    </div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/vedankita/jgunov4y/4/)

Now I want to expand like this on click.

[image]

I want to expand div as per content width and height, what can I do for this. When I click on div it's information is sliding down. Now I have to create like this, when I click on div it's parent's height and width should be change as per sliding content width and height.Please help.

Comment: Please check my example. When I click on div it's information is sliding down. Now I have to create like this, when I click on div it's parent's height and width should be change as per sliding content width and height.

Comment: I really wanna help, but I don't understand your question. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: thanks @ivanasetiawan i just want to on click on div it will expand as per its content width and height and other tabs will fit as per their space require.